# Why does an additional -1/x term in the integrand of the Mellin transform representation of the Riemann zeta function not change its value?

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, riemann-zeta, mellin-transform

Using Mellin transforms, the product of the Riemann zeta function and the gamma function can be expressed as the following integral:

$$\zeta\left(s\right)\mathrm{\Gamma}\left(s\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{1}{e^x-1}\right)x^{s-1}dx}$$

However, I have also read sources stating that the following representation (apparently from Whittaker-Watson) is also valid for the critical strip 0 < Re(s) < 1 :

$$\zeta\left(s\right)\mathrm{\Gamma}\left(s\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{1}{e^x-1}-\frac{1}{x}\right)x^{s-1}dx}$$

It is amazing to me that the addition of the term $(-\frac{1}{x})$ in the integrand of the second representation does not change the value of the integral at all for any value of s in the critical strip!

Can anyone provide a mathematical explanation for why and how this is the case?

Comment: I think your question is misguided. The original integral is only valid for $\Re(s)>1$. Apparently adding the $\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)$ term to the integrand shifts the convergence to $0\lt\Re(s)\lt1$.

Answer (score 2):

Compare with the following:

For $\Re(s) > 1$, $$\frac1{s-1}=\int_0^1 x^{s-2}dx$$
For $\Re(s) < 1$, $$\frac1{s-1}=-\int_1^\infty x^{s-2}dx$$

This is also how we prove your formula, as for $\Re(s) > 1$, $$\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)-\frac1{s-1}=\int_0^1 (\frac1{e^x-1}-\frac1x) x^{s-1}dx+\int_1^\infty \frac1{e^x-1} x^{s-1}dx$$
and the RHS stays analytic for $\Re(s)> 0$, thus providing the analytic continuation of the LHS.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_0^1 x^{s-2}dx=\left.\frac{x^{s-1}}{s-1}\right|_0^1=\frac1{s-1}$$

$$\int_1^\infty x^{s-2}dx=\left.\frac{x^{s-1}}{s-1}\right|_1^\infty=-\frac1{s-1}$$

since if $\;s=a+bi\;,\;\;a,b\in\Bbb R\;,\;0<a<1\;$, then

$$\left|x^{s-1}\right|=\left|e^{\left(a-1+bi\right)\log x}\right|=e^{(a-1)\log x}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}0\,,\,\,\text{because}\;\;a-1<0\,,\,\,\log x\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\infty$$

Thus adding $\;-\frac1x\;$ to the parentheses in the integrand is just like adding zero to the whole integral

Comment: $\int\limits_0^1 -\frac{1}{x}\,x^{s-1}\,dx=-\frac{1}{s-1}$ is only valid for $\Re(s)>1$, whereas $\int\limits_1^\infty -\frac{1}{x}\,x^{s-1}\,dx=\frac{1}{s-1}$ is only valid for $\Re(s)<1$, so is your argument not flawed? I believe $\int\limits_0^\infty -\frac{1}{x}\,x^{s-1}\,dx$ actually corresponds to the pole of $\zeta(s)\, \Gamma(s)$ at $s=1$.

Comment: @StevenClark You are completely right. Thankx